# Posting data to Windows Azure Mobile Services Mysql table Using a Custom API from Android App

Tags: javascript, mysql, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am new to Windows Azure mobile services , and now i need to post sign up data to Mysql table in Windows Azure Mobile Services.

I have  made a pojo class (USER) , and saved user entered data to them , and now calling custom api line using this line.

```
ListenableFuture<User> result = mClient.invokeApi( "signup", User.class );

        Log.d("try","THIS LINE IS OKAY");


        Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable exc) {
                createAndShowDialog((Exception) exc, "Error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(User result) {
                createAndShowDialog( " item(s)inserted", "Success");

            }
        });
    }
```

I have created a Custom API , in Mobile Services ,

```
exports.post= function(request, response) { 
     var queryString = "INSERT INTO User (user_name, user_email) VALUES (?,?)" ;   

      request.service.mssql.query(queryString, [request.query.username, request.query.user_email], { 
          success: function(results) { 
                 request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results); 
          } 
     }); 
};
```

While running app , i am getting a Internal Server Error 500.

Any one please help me to resolve issue,

Comment: Do you see any errors in the log tab of the Azure portal for your mobile service?

Comment: You're also not passing any parameters when you call the `invokeApi` method, and your custom API in the script is trying to read them (username, user_email). That will certainly lead to failures.

Comment: I am trying default update method now..could you please have  look to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665472/update-a-specific-row-in-windows-azure-mobile-services-sql-database    @carlosfigueira

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @carlosfiguera, you need to pass parameters to invokeApi. Here's he documentation on how to do this: [How to: call a custom API in Android](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-how-to-use-client-library/#custom-api).