# Update a specific row in Windows Azure Mobile Services SQL Database

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to update a specific row in Table of windows azure mobile services.

item is a reference to a row in the ToDoItem table, which has had some changes made to it.

```
private void updateItem(final ToDoItem item) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                mToDoTable.update(item).get();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (item.isComplete()) {
                            mAdapter.remove(item);
                        }
                        refreshItemsFromTable();
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

and my Script in table is

```
function update(item, user, request) {

    request.execute();

}
```

I want to select a row using an ID. While running this code, its just inserting a new row. Where i have to pass , ID , to update only the specified row.

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question?  Are you using Android?  What is the expected result, and what is actually happening?  Is the problem in your client UI or on the server?

Comment: Also, are you using MySQL on Mobile Services?  That isn't a supported option out of the box, so how is that configured?